# Niveis de Persistência de dados nas aplicações android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistência

Estou estudando persistência para o android, entretanto estou com dificuldade em entender os níveis de persistência que fazem nas aplicações.

**Vi que existem 5 tipos:**

- onSavedIntanceState
- SharedPreferences
- Database
- Internal/External Storage
- Server

**Minhas dúvidas são:**

- Quando devo usar cada tipo?
- Consigo substituir um SharedPreferences por um onSavedIntanceState ou vice-versa?
- Os bancos de dados não funcionam da mesma forma que um servidor ou como o armazenamento interno?
- Por que devo utilizar esses outros dois se fazem "a mesma função"?
- Posso compartilhar essas preferências entre si?
- Web service se encaixa num tipo de servidor?

Comment: Meio grande esta sua pergunta amigo!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski um pouquinho =P, mas eu ja fiz muita confusão com essa historia de persistencia, então eu achei legal colocar aqui essa pergunta porque é um assunto que muita gente iria ter duvida

Comment: Se você quiser uma resposta mais completa e mais confiável, podes acessar a própria documentação: [Opções de Armazenamento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos lá:

- **onSavedIntanceState** :
  Este guarda informações adicionais da tela,  como variáveis que não estão associados a View,  para quando recriar a Activity, os dados sejam populados!

Ele salva (temporariamente) as informações da tela quando destruída através do método [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=pt-br#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) e disponibiliza através do método [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=pt-br#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

O transporte desta informações é feito através de um [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html?hl=pt-br).

[FONTE](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=pt-br)

- **SharedPreferences**: Geralmente utilizado para guardar preferências!

Você pode usar [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) para salvar dados primitivos: booleanos, floats, ints, longs e strings. Esses dados persistirão nas sessões do usuário (mesmo se o aplicativo for eliminado).

[FONTE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

- **Database**: Por padrão o Android suporta o [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), sendo utilizado para armazenar dados mais robustos e complexos.

Todos os bancos de dados criados poderão ser acessados pelo nome em qualquer classe do aplicativo, mas não fora dele.

O método recomendado para criar um novo banco de dados SQLite é criar uma subclasse de [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) e modificar o método [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)), em que é possível executar um comando SQLite para criar tabelas no banco de dados.

Você pode executar consultas do SQLite usando os métodos de [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) de [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), que aceitam vários parâmetros de consulta, como tabela a consultar, projeção, seleção, colunas e agrupamento, entre outros. Para consultas complexas, como as que exigem aliases de coluna, use [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html), que fornece vários métodos convenientes para a criação de consultas.

- **Internal/External Storage**: Através deste é possível salvar/ler arquivos.
- **Server**: Este é um serviço responsável por salvar e disponibilizar os dados.

**DUVÍDAS:**

> Quando devo usar cada tipo?

Depende da situação e o que seu App se propõem a fazer!

Dados simples, como preferências do usuário, podem ser armazenados no SharedPreferences.

Cadastros, informações mais complexas, como Lista de Amigos por exemplo, podem ser armazenados com o SQLite.

Nestes casos, estas informações permanecem no Smartphone do usuário, em caso de perda ou roubo, as informações serão perdidas também! Então pode se salvar estas informações em um Servidor (através de um serviço) para quando o usuário realizar o Login em um novo aparelho, estas informações sejam atualizadas!

Então depende do que você irá propor com seu App!

> Consigo substituir um SharedPreferences por um onSavedIntanceState ou
>   vice-versa?

Você pode ao invés de usar o `Bundle` deste método, salvar as informações no `SharedPreferences` e regatar quando recriar a tela!

Mas isto (pessoalmente) me cheira Gambiarra!

Os dois tem finalidades diferentes!  O `onSavedIntanceState` é utilizado para salvar os dados em tela e logo em seguida exibir (quando o usuário muda de Portrait para landscape, por exemplo!), em quanto o `SharedPreferences` salva as informações mesmo após finalizar o app.

> Os bancos de dados não funcionam da mesma forma que um servidor ou
>   como o armazenamento interno?

O banco de Dados (no caso o SQlite) armazena as informações no Smartphone.

O servidor além do Banco de dados, possui um serviço (uma aplicação) responsável por inserir e disponibilizar os dados!

> Por que devo utilizar esses outros dois se fazem "a mesma função"?

Como disse, isto vai depender de você utilizar ou não!

Se seu App possui dados que não alteram frequentemente, então buscar toda vez em que o usuário entra no App seria um desperdício no uso da internet.

Ao invés de buscar do servidor todas as vezes, você pode trazer e armazenar estas informações através do Banco de dados interno (SQlite).

> Posso compartilhar essas preferências entre si?

Se entendi, está falando do SharedPreferences, como dito acima, este é disponível apenas em seu App, cabe a você compartilhar ou não!

> Web service se encaixa num tipo de servidor?

Sim! como dito, o Web Service é responsável por disponibilizar e armazenar as informações no Servidor.