# Salvar email digitado e usa-lo em um textview?

Tags: android

Quero pegar o email que a pessoa digitou no login para exibir ele em um textview , como eu faço isso? 
obs , Esse edit text ja esta sendo usado para fazer o login

Comment: EditText, SharedPreferences, é o que afinal?

Comment: mudei a pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Eu imagino que você queira abrir uma outra activity e exibir em um TextView, o e-mail digitado na tela de login.

Se for apenas para exibição e utilizar como prova de conceito, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

**LoginActivity.class**

```
String txt = editText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("login", txt);     
startActivity(intent);
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null){
    String email = b.getString("login");
    txtEmail.setText(email);
}
```

Mas eu oriento a você criar uma base local, para não ter problema em exibição, caso você continue com uma navegação em outras telas e em ter de retornar para a MainActivity, por exemplo.

Espero poder ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de persistência de dados é usar o `SharedPreference` como mostra na documentação sobre [Como salvar conjuntos de valor-chave](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br). Veja abaixo um exemplo de como salvar, considerando tenha uma variável `EditText` com nome nome `myEditText`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("str_email", myEditText.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Para resgatar:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = pref.getString("str_email", null);
myEditText.setText(email);
```

Veja mais detalhes nesta pergunta sobre [Salvar valor em SharedPreference](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-valor-em-sharedpreference).

Desta forma, em qualquer momento de sua aplicação, é possível regatar o valor que foi salvo numa determinada chave. Veja aqui em [Niveis de Persistência de dados nas aplicações Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193765/niveis-de-persist%C3%AAncia-de-dados-nas-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-android) outras abordagens.