# Como manter o texto de um TextView depois da App fechar

Tags: java, android

Boas, eu sou novo no Android, mas gostaria de saber como posso manter/guardar a informação que está num TextView, para que esta não seja apagada quando fechar aplicação.

```
     public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

                @Override
                  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity);
                  EscreverData();}

               private void EscreverData(){
                  TextView datas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datas);
                  datas.append(strDate);}}
```

Basicamente o que eu pretendo é, quando esta atividade inicia, obter a data e hora e mostrar essa informação na TextView. No entanto, eu gostava que ela continuasse a armazenar as datas antigas e não apagá-las cada vez que a atividade é iniciada novamente. Já tentei pesquisar um pouco e acho que uma boa solução poderia ser SharedPreferences mas eu não sei como usar. Obrigado se me puderem ajudar

Comment: Você já tem algum código? Seria interessante se você colocasse ele aqui pra ajudar a identificarmos a solução (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada em SharedPreferences.

Comment: @rLinhares aqui está... se me puderes ajudar agradecia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de persistência de dados é usar o `SharedPreference` como mostra na documentação sobre [Como salvar conjuntos de valor-chave](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br). Veja abaixo um exemplo de como salvar, considerando tenha uma variável qualquer com um texto qualquer:

```
String value = "Um texto qualquer";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("str_textview", value);
editor.commit();
```

Para resgatar:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String text = pref.getString("str_textview", null);
meuTextView.setText(text );
```

Veja mais detalhes nesta pergunta sobre [Salvar valor em SharedPreference](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-valor-em-sharedpreference).

Desta forma, em qualquer momento de sua aplicação, é possível regatar o valor que foi salvo numa determinada chave. Veja aqui em [Niveis de Persistência de dados nas aplicações Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193765/niveis-de-persist%C3%AAncia-de-dados-nas-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-android) outras abordagens.

#### No [**Kotlin**](https://kotlinlang.org/) ficaria assim:

```
val value = "Um texto qualquer"
val sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedpreferences.edit()
editor.putString("str_textview", value)
editor.commit()
```

Para resgatar:

```
val pref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE)
val text = pref.getString("str_textview", null)
myTextView.setText(text)
```

Comment: eu pus o codigo na pergunta, será que me podes ajudar a juntar tudo? eu só não sei onde colocar o resto do código que tu disponibilizaste
Obrigado já agora pela ajuda

Comment: @EduardoBrito você então queria uma lista de datas, no qual seria armazenadas todas as datas antigas? Ou somente a primeira data no qual o usuário entrou a primeira vez?

Comment: Sim é mesmo isso. Uma lista com por exemplo as 5 últimas datas

Comment: @EduardoBrito minha resposta estava correta antes da edição. Quando você editou ela, acabou invalidando ela. Sugiro criar uma outra pergunta detalhando melhor sua questão, porque uma resposta para sua dúvida, não tem nada a ver com isso aqui.

Comment: @EduardoBrito Você poderia criar uma pergunta com título: "Como armazenar em uma lista a data de acesso do usuário?" ... ai você descreve seu problema.

Comment: @EduardoBrito Porque não envolve somente o TextView. Envolve também um ListView. etc.

Comment: se calhar é isso mesmo que eu vou fazer Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228729/como-armazenar-numa-lista-as-5-%c3%baltimas-datas-de-abertura-de-uma-atividade-androi

@acklay aqui esta

Comment: @EduardoBrito vi que você colocou uma pergunta. Eu ia tentar colocar uma resposta lá, mas já vi que você respondeu. Se essa resposta aqui foi útil e se quiser valida-la, fique a vontade. Qualquer coisa estou por aqui.

Comment: muito obrigado por toda a ajuda. Eu sou novo nestas coisas e ainda sinto algumas dificuldades. 
Sim vou valida-la esta aqui, pois ajudou bastante a resolver a outra