# Como armazenar numa lista as 5 últimas datas de abertura de uma atividade Android

Tags: java, android

```
 public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

            @Override
              protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity);
              EscreverData();}

           private void EscreverData(){
              TextView datas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datas);
              datas.append(strDate);}}
```

Aqui está o meu código, só que, como podem ver, a única coisa que ele faz é apresentar, na TextView, a data de entrada, daquele momento, na atividade. O que eu pretendia mesmo era apresentar na TextView as 5 últimas datas de entrada na atividade, sem que desaparecessem, quando saísse da aplicação, ou seja, armazena-las numa lista...
Se alguém me puder ajudar agradecia

Comment: Use SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        TextView datas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datas);
        datas.setMaxLines(5);
//Restaura as preferencias gravadas
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        String a = settings.getString("PrefUsuario", "");
        datas.append(strDate + "\n" + a);}

/**Chamado quando a Activity é encerrada.*/
@Override
protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        TextView datas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datas);
        String a = datas.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("PrefUsuario", a);
//Confirma a gravação dos dados
        editor.commit();}}
```

Aqui está, penso eu, a solução para a minha própria pergunta - Através das SharedPreferences